# Schedule job in Azure for an console app

Tags: azure

We are in the process of shifting to azure. We have a separate server where a console app (Written in C#) which is a scheduled task. It runs only twice a day.

What would be the best way to leverage this in Azure to save money to get charged only to the time the console process is running

I did come across web jobs and scheduler but no sure what is the best approach

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not worried with scalability. If that is the case you should be fine with WebJobs.

Comment: i am not worried about scalability. If i use it as independent WebJob and setup a schedule would i be charged when there is nothing happening?

Comment: Azure Web Jobs is part of the Azure Web Sites offering. So you can simply look at the pricing of Azure Web Sites. You can even use the free tier if the related bandwidth, cpu time limitations are suitable to your needs.